# How to execute a shell command synchronously on multiple client machines?

Tags: bash, shell, networking, ssh, server

I am trying to run a simple bash command(ex: `ssh user@client1 date`) on several remote machines. I can do this by writing a bash script like this(consider there is no password for client machines):

```
ssh user@client1 date
ssh user@client2 date
ssh user@client3 date
ssh user@client4 date
ssh user@client5 date
.
.
.
ssh user@clientn date
```

However, what this does is simply iterate through the given machines and execute the `date` command one by one, like a `for` loop.
What I am willing to achieve is, executing these commands at the **exact same time**.
The first solution that came into my mind is fixing the clock on every client to the same time, then using the `at` command and setting the execution on a specific time, addressing every client to run their respective commands on that same clock tick. This solution makes the above script, morphed into this(consider this script started at 9:30 am, and finished in less than 5 minutes.):

```
at 9:35 <<< "ssh user@client1 date"
at 9:35 <<< "ssh user@client2 date"
at 9:35 <<< "ssh user@client3 date"
at 9:35 <<< "ssh user@client4 date"
at 9:35 <<< "ssh user@client5 date"
.
.
.
at 9:35 <<< "ssh user@clientn date"
```

I don't think this is a good solution and I can't stop thinking that I am approaching this completely wrong or rather lacking knowledge somewhere in the network architecture.

Also, running multiple threads and creating *n* amount of bash instances is not acceptable as well, because the number *n* can go up to **thousands**.

Comment: You will not get commands to run on thousands of machines from 1 source in sync.  Even ansible could not run all these in sync.  Send the `at` command to the clients, so they will trigger the command at the specified time.  Each client will have to send the output to a log, which you can later collect.  There is no easy way to receive output from thousands of machines at the same exact time anyway.  Or setup something like Control-M or Autosys with agents software...

Comment: And sync your clocks with NTP.

Comment: sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/); to answer the question re: *`approaching this completely wrong`* we'd need to know what you're really trying to accomplish and why it *must* be performed synchronously across thousands of hosts

Comment: @markp-fuso What I am willing to achieve is to create a custom test service. I have my UAT test application programmed. But instead of writing a seperate load tester and sending all the requests from one machine, I want the UAT tests to be run on the each individual client machine, on the same time. Why? Because the scenario is exactly that.
Sure, running _n_ threads from one machine, doing the load test, then looping through the clients and doing the UAT tests sounds reasonable, but I still want to do them together in one method. That way, I believe the test would be more trustable.

Comment: @Nic3500 Collecting the logs doesn't have to be synchronous. We have enough time for that:)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using & to send ssh task in background, so you can launch all your ssh thru the loop like this :

```
ssh user@client1 date &
ssh user@client2 date &
ssh user@client3 date &
ssh user@client4 date &
ssh user@client5 date &
```

Comment: That will not work for thousands of client systems like the question stated.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts spring to mind:

- **Subscribe** all of the clients to a common MQTT topic with a broker such as `mosquitto`, then **publish** a command `GO` on that channel whenever you want them to start
- As above, but subscribe and publish via Redis
- Start all clients waiting for a UDP broadcast on your network, e.g. simply with `nectat` and then UDP broadcast a `GO` message, also with `netcat`.

Comment: All 3 sound so smart. I will try them respectively, and return feedback. Thanks!